# Using BETWEEN Clause in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I want to fetch data using **BETWEEN** clause from MySql database.

In client side, I created 2 inline calender with JQuery and emit selected **date** value with socket.io;

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#d',
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
      console.log(dateAsString);
      socket.emit('socketfromDate', $('#d').val());
    }
  });

  $('#toDate').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#x',
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
      console.log(dateAsString);
      socket.emit('sockettoDate', $('#x').val());
    }
  });
```

In server side, If I receive '**toDate**' value after '**fromDate**' value, MySql query must fetch data between these days.

```
 var  fromDate_query,
      toDate_query;

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

      socket.on('socketfromDate', function(fromDate) {
        console.log();
        console.log("----------------------------------");
        console.log("Selected dateTime 'from': " + fromDate); //output: Selected dateTime 'from': 2017-07-01 
        console.log("----------------------------------");
        console.log();
        fromDate_query = fromDate;
      });

      socket.on('sockettoDate', function(toDate) {
        console.log();
        console.log("----------------------------------");
        console.log("Selected dateTime 'to': " + toDate); //output: Selected dateTime 'to': 2017-07-13
        console.log("----------------------------------");
        console.log();
        toDate_query = toDate;

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM report WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND  ?", [fromDate_query, toDate_query], function(err, rows) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              var row = rows[i];
              console.log("**********************************");
              console.log("Possible machine: " + row.machine); //output: nothing
              console.log("**********************************");
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Problem is, nothing happens.

*What is the best approach for querying between two days?*

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your code :

1. Using two events to seperately send the to & from date whereas, you need both the data to process the SQL query.
2. Why use sockets when you can use/ would be better to use http requests for transactional stuff.
3. The query should be done inside the events, because that is where the data will be present when you emit from the client side.

To answer your question. You would have to refactor your code to remove two seperate events to one event which will receive both you to & from date like so :

```
   socket.on('dates', function(dateData) {

        var toDate_query = dateData.toDate;
        var fromDate_query = dateData.fromDate;
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM report WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND  ?", [fromDate_query, toDate_query], function(err, rows) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              var row = rows[i];
              console.log("**********************************");
              console.log("Possible machine: " + row.machine); //output: nothing
              console.log("**********************************");
            }
          }
        });
```

Apart from this, You would have to refactor your front-end to emit the event only when both the dates have been selected.

EDIT : 
BONUS POINT -> Please release the SQL connection once you have received the queried data

Comment: I couldn't refactor my client side but while I'm trying, I figured out what is the problem; there is no record for my picked dates and that's why it shows nothing. :)
And also I don't want to refresh page, that's why I'm using socket.io.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @erayaras Even if it did have any records, your code will not work as expected. Please carefully review the points I have listed above & maybe read up on socket.io event listeners and scopes of objects inside the event listeners.